# Answers to deleted posts are automaticly marked to be undeleted and viewable?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-questions

Today I noticed that I've lost 15 reputation because a user decided to delete the question where my answer was accepted by the user. I don't mind this, but there are few things that I don't understand:

1. Why am I able to view the deleted question? I don't have the required reputation for it. But I think it's because my own post got deleted as well.
2. Why does it say that I voted to undelete my answer? Yet when I click undelete, it asks me if I want to undelete it and gives me an error that posts to deleted questions can't be undeteled. Is it because it'll automaticly undelete my answer in case the user decides to undelete the question?

PS: This is not a complaint about the deleted post or the loss of the reputation. I'm simply trying to understand how it works. That's all.

This is the post I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584385/removing-a-character-from-text-using-strpos-substr-in-php/

Comment: @user0042 Perhaps he unaccepted my answer before deletion. If you check the history of my answer, he tried to edit it and remove everything as well. According to the triage history, an attempt was made to turn my answer into advertisement. Perhaps OP's account is compromised?

Comment: More likely the user was trying to hide the fact that they got help on SO with their assignment. They had to unaccept your answer to be able to delete the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Yes, you can see the question because you have a deleted answer there.
2. It's just an oddity in how delete/undelete votes are stored. You'd previously deleted and undeleted the answer yourself. But the system doesn't "clear" undelete votes until it gets deleted again, so if something deletes your post outside of the usual process (in this case an automated process that silently marks it as deleted with the question) then the system thinks that undelete vote from before is still pending and lists it as such. There are bug reports about it that have been lying around for years.

Comment: May you please link to such bug report?

Comment: "There are bug reports about it that have been lying around for years." surely not longer  than 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons: Undelete votes don't appear to time out.